# Modifier added from Python operator not being applied

Tags: python, operator, panel

My operator duplicates the active object, adds a solidify modifier to it, then applies it.

When run from my panel it works EXCEPT it does not apply the modifier and I can see it still under the duped object in the Outliner (I can then manual apply it, apparently correctly).

When I run the operator directly from the Python Console it DOES apply.

I've verified that after the duplicate, the new object is active and the sole selected object.

I must being doing something wrong that only manifests in a panel context, but I'm stumped.  Below is the complete test script.

```
# Blender 2.82a
import bpy

class TestSolidifyOp(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.test_solidify"
    bl_label = "Test solidify"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        orig=context.active_object

        bpy.ops.object.duplicate()
        ob = context.active_object

        if orig is ob:   # Just to show orig obj is NOT still active
             return{'CANCELLED'}

        mod = ob.modifiers.new("Solidify", 'SOLIDIFY')
        mod.thickness = -1
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Solidify")

        return {'FINISHED'}

class TestSolidifyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Test solidify Panel"
    bl_idname = "PANEL_PT_tsolid"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.mode == 'OBJECT')

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("object.test_solidify")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bpy.utils.register_class(TestSolidifyOp)
    bpy.utils.register_class(TestSolidifyPanel)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Override the context.**

TBH can't see why this is not working, the properties panel can be fickle, for example with `context.object`

Suggest two changes, make an override dictionary to be sure to be sure the object known as ob is the one having its modifier applied. Secondly using `mod.name` to identify the modifier ensures it is the last one added, in case the object has another already.

**Blender 3.2+**

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

with context.temp_override(object=bpy.data.objects['Cube']):
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Subdivision")
```

**Blender 2.8+**

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply({"object" : bpy.data.objects['Cube']}, modifier="Subdivision")
```

Comment: Solved!  Thank you!  I didn't even know about overriding context (even though it is well documented).

Comment: That temp_override doesn't seem to be in usable state yet though: https://developer.blender.org/T100664